# Sonarqube prepare analysis step failing in azuredevops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I am attempting to run the sonarqube analysis task in my azure devops pipeline but I am getting this error:
##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"172.28.4.132","port":9000

This IP address is a VM. I have tried to troubleshoot and I am stuck.
Here is my pipeline setup:
[image: pipeline setup]

Here is the prepare analyis setup:
[image: analysis setup]
[image: service endpoint]

Comment: hey- no my issue was not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"172.28.4.132","port":9000

Based on the error message, it seems that Azure Pipeline Agent can't connect the SonarQube Instance in your VM.

You need to check if the Agent could ping your VM(SonarQube located). And you need to check if the Agent IP is added to the VM firewall whitelist.

Here are two methods:

For self-hosted agent, you can try to install the self-hosted agent directly on the VM where sonarqube is located.

For Microsoft-hosted agent, you can add the Microsoft-hosted agents IP to the VM whitelist.

The IPs of the agents are not fixed, and updated weekly.

For more detailed info about the  Microsoft-hosted agents IP, you could refer to this doc: [Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking)(Download the json file and find the corresponding IP list according to your organization region)